# Multiple devices on 5v pin

Tags: lcd, potentiometer

Im soldering an LCD screen to my Arduino as I don't have a breadboard and plan on it being permanent. I'm wondering how I should connect the potentiometer (to control contrast).

If I connect it as the first component in series, will this affect the main power to the LCD?

Should I use both 5v pins on the Arduino instead? (Mine has two anyway, I dont know if the official one does).

Would splitting a cable work?

Im new to electronics so sorry if the questions are stupid.

I intend to use the circuit from: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HelloWorld. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: why would the potentiometer be in series with the LCD? ... it is not is series in the circuit that you linked

Comment: I meant it as an option as I'm unsure of connecting in parallel. A better question would be how can I connect two things to the 5v. Sorry and thanks!

Comment: use two wires ... i do not understand what you are really asking

Comment: yes, you can connect several things to the 5v line, within current limits of course.

Comment: @dandavis would you mind helping me with this? I would be connecting the vdd and anode pins of the lcd to the 5v aswell as the 5v of a humidity sensor. Is this too much? Thanks

Comment: since neither of those devices use very much power, you're good.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Related article I wrote: https://www.electricrcaircraftguy.com/2014/02/arduino-power-current-and-voltage.html